# Why are there both antinodes at both ends of the tube?

Tags: waves, pressure, acoustics, boundary-conditions, harmonics

I learned stationary/standing waves the other day. **For stationary waves in open tubes, the textbook says both ends must have an antinode. Can anyone tell me why?** (shown as figure)

[image]

**And also, when playing with the instruments like guitar, what's the number of harmonic on the string, i.e. how many antinodes and nodes are there on the string?**

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/256008/2451

Answer (score 3):

It's a pressure *node* as the pressure at the open ends of tube is  atmospheric pressure. It's then automatically a displacement *antinode* because  the equation of motion
$$
\rho_o \partial_t v = - \partial_x P
$$
means that  a standing wave
$$
P(x,t)= A\sin(kx) \sin (\omega t)
$$
with a pressure node at $x=0$ makes the velocity obey
$$
\rho_0 \omega^2   v(x,t)= \partial^2_{xt} P= A k\omega \cos(kx) \cos (\omega t),
$$
which has a velocity (and hence a displacement) maximum at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The air molecules are free to move at the open end of a tube, so there's an antinode.  At a closed end, there must be a node as the air molecules don't move there.

That's similar to a wave in a string, at the fixed ends the string can't move and there are nodes there.  The first harmonic for a string (the fundamental), has two nodes at the ends and one antinode in the middle.  The second harmonic has two antinodes etc...